# how to build a function in python to solve: if company X's label changes from 0 to 1 once in a year then we return 1, otherwise return 0?

Tags: python

```
   company  year  label
0        a  2011      1
1        a  2011      1
2        a  2012      1
3        a  2013      1
4        b  2015      0
5        b  2015      1
6        b  2015      0
7        b  2016      1
8        b  2016      0
9        b  2016      0
10       b  2017      0
11       b  2017      0
```

the expected output for the example would be

```
   company  year  label
0        a  2011      1
1        a  2012      1
2        a  2013      1
3        b  2015      1
4        b  2016      0
5        b  2017      0
```

if company X's label changes from 0 to 1 once in a year then we return 1, otherwise return 0.
for example, company b in 2015 even though the final label is 0 but since it has changed from 0 to 1 once we still return 1. In 2016, the label of company b changed from 1 to 0 so we return 0.

I tried several ways but still didn't work it out.

Comment: what if it turns 1  two times in a year?

Comment: and what if it is 1 throughout the year?

Comment: - if it turns 1 two times a year then return 1(like once the process "0->1" appears in a year for a company, we return 1) 
-if it is 1 through out the year the we still return 1

Comment: Can you share the expected output and what you've tried for your example data? It's easier to help with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do you use `pandas` or only `python`?

Comment: thanks for replying and I've added the expected output. I only used python.

Comment: How are these sorted?

Comment: Ok.  Your output doesn't match at least my interpretation of your problem statement.  You say "changes from 0 to 1" is the event you want to catch.  That only happens once the way I see it.

Comment: I thought maybe the logic you want is "is ever 1 in a year", but that doesn't explain "b 2016".  It also isn't that the company "ends a year with 1", as that doesn't account for "b 2015".  I can't figure out any logic that leads to your output.

Comment: Why do "b 2015" and "b 2016" have different results?

Comment: actually 'label' is a rate for each company, label 1 means bad and label 0 means good. the question I want to figure out is that once the rate dropped in a year then the final label would be 1(bad).

Comment: because in 2015, the label changes from 0 to 1(good to bad) once, so the rate dropped for on time. In 2016, the label is 0 through out the year.

Comment: But that's not true.  The difference between "b 2015" and "b 2016" is only that "b 2015" starts out a 0 and "b 2016" starts out a 1.  Both are 1 at some point and end up 0.

Comment: I found a rule, but I don't see that it makes sense.  "1 if the company started out 0, was 1 at some point, and went back to 0 OR the company was always a 1". - that's also incomplete, as you don't show a case where something starts out a 0 and ends up a 1.

Comment: oh sorry for that. you are right and that means the rate of "b 2016" never dropped so the final rate should be 0(good). and for "b 2015" even though it ends up 0 but the rate dropped once, the final rate should be 1(bad).

Comment: darn.  I thought we were going to have a breakthrough.  But this latest explanation matches your expected output, so I don't see that anything has changed.

Comment: You say that the rate of "b 2016" never dropped, but it did.  Are you missing the first "b 2016" of 1 maybe in whatever you are looking at?

Comment: label of "b 2016" changes from 1 to 0 which means "bad" to "good" so it actually increased

Comment: My best guess at what's going on here is that you want to know if a company was ever a 1 in a given year, and "b 2016" should be a 1.  That would be a simple rule that would then fit the data...was the company ever bad in a year.

Comment: in regards to your last comment...didn't "b 2015" do the same thing?

Comment: the rate of "b 2016" increased once and never dropped so it's good.  the rate of "b 2015" dropped first so whatever how many times it increased after that, the rate should sill be 1(bad). so for simple meaning, i just want to find the rate that dropped.

Comment: Ok, then that explains the two 'b' entries.  But why are the 'a' entries a 1?

Comment: cause labels for company "a" never change and stay at "1"(bad). even the rate did not drop but still bad

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE 2: After a lot of back and forth in comments, I finally figured out what you want.  Please see my other answer (I couldn't bear to get rid of this one, so rather than replace it, I created a new one.  I don't know what the etiquette is for doing that.

UPDATE:  You only added your expected output after I submitted my answer.
I'd change my answer to result in the output you want if I could come up with a reasonable rule to be able to do so.  But as I state in my comments on the question, I can't find a rule that accounts for the output you provide.  The code here does what you still say you want, "if company X's label changes from 0 to 1 once in a year", which I see only happening once.  If you assume that each company starts at `0`, so an initial `1` is a "change", then you almost get your expected output, but then "b 2016" should be a `1`.

I'm not sure what you mean by "return 1".  This code assumes that the incoming data is sorted by year, but makes no assumptions about the grouping of company names.  It builds a list of the occurrences of the event you're looking for in `result`:

```
state = {}
result = []
for line in data.splitlines():
    if not line:
        continue
    i, company, year, label = line.split()
    state.setdefault(company, [])
    if state[company]:
        last_year, last_label = state[company]
        if last_year == year and last_label == '0' and label == '1':
            result.append((company, year)) # <- A hit!  Do whatever you want to do here
    state[company] = (year, label)

for r in result:
    company, year = r
    print(f"company: {company}  year:{year}")
```

Result:

```
company: b  year:2015
```

If your data set allows for adding another column, then you could apply this same basic logic to that, but set that new column to `1` or `0` instead of adding the row to `results` or not.  I just don't know what to do with "return 1" as that isn't a visible thing and it isn't clear what would be returning it or what what would receive that value.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for the replying and i'm sorry for the unclear description. I've added the expected output.

Comment: After finally getting the whole story from you, I submitted a fresh new answer that gives you just what you requested. (I was bored).

Answer (score 0):

After many back and forths in the comments, I think I finally know what you want.  What you want is kinda wacky.  Here's what I think that is:

score of 0 is good, score of 1 is bad

Company 'a' is always bad, so company 'a' is always a score of 1

Otherwise, a company is only bad if it started the year at a label of '0', at some point in the year has a label of '1', and then ends up with a label of '0' at the end of the year.

And here's the code that implements that:

```
data = """
0        a  2011      1
1        a  2011      1
2        a  2012      1
3        a  2013      1
4        b  2015      0
5        b  2015      1
6        b  2015      0
7        b  2016      1
8        b  2016      0
9        b  2016      0
10       b  2017      0
11       b  2017      0
"""

# State 2 is bad. We run a little state machine for each company/year combo.
# We call each company/year combo a 'case'.  For each line in the data, we adjust
# the state of a case based on the current label and the prior label for that case.
states = {}
result = []
for line in data.splitlines():
    if not line:
        continue  # skip empty lines
    i, company, year, label = line.split()  # pull apart a line of data
    case = company + '|' + year  # compute the case id for this line
    # Compute the next state for this case...
    if company == 'a':
        state = '2'  # Company 'a' is always bad, which is state '2'
    else:
        if case in states:  # If we've seen this case before...
            prior_state = states[case]  # Get the prior state for this case
            # States are:
            #    0 = has always been a 0
            #    1 = started out a 1
            #    2 = started out a 0, has been a 1, and is now a 0
            #    3 = started out a 0 and is now a 1

            # Update our state machine's state
            if prior_state == '1':
                state = '1'  # Once a '1', always a '1', so we'll always be good
            elif label == '1':
                state = '3'  # If prior state is not '1', then label == '1' takes us to state '3'
            elif prior_state == '0':
                state = '0' # Label is zero and prior_state is zero leaves us at state '0'
            else:
                state = '2'  # Label is zero and prior_state is not zero takes us to state '2'
        else:
            state = label  # A case's state starts out as the label on its first line
    # Store the new state having processed the line
    states[case] = state

# Run through our state table, and for each case, compute the score based on the state
# and display the final result
for  i, (case, state) in enumerate(states.items()):
    company, year = case.split('|')
    score = 1 if state == '2' else 0
    print(f"{i} {company} {year} {score}")
```

Result:

```
0 a 2011 1
1 a 2012 1
2 a 2013 1
3 b 2015 1
4 b 2016 0
5 b 2017 0
```